# How to group sublist's with matching values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with sublist's in it and want to group them based on a common value.

For example:

```
my_list = [["John", 1], ["Mark", 3], ["Peter", 5], ["Mark", 6], ["Mark", 33], ["John", 2]]
```

I would like to group these based on the first value (the name). The desired result would be:

```
grouped_list = [[["John", 1], ["John", 2]], [["Mark", 3], ["Mark", 6], ["Mark", 33]], [["Peter", 5]]]
```

Comment: Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: What have you tried?
Have you looked into the `groupby` operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Since you want to only group by the first element of each sublist, you must supply a custom key.

```
import itertools

[list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(my_list), lambda x: x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[[['John', 1], ['John', 2]],
 [['Mark', 3], ['Mark', 6], ['Mark', 33]],
 [['Peter', 5]]]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! That definitely does it, I'll have to read into the documentation to understand the usage better.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. I prefer the answer by @user3483203 using `itertools.groupby` but here is a solution with no imports;

```
result = []
name_to_index = {}

for l in my_list:
    if l[0] in name_to_index:
        result[name_to_index.get(l[0])].append(l)
    else:
        result.append([l])
        name_to_index[l[0]] = len(result) - 1
```

Output:

```
[[['John', 1], ['John', 2]], [['Mark', 3], ['Mark', 6], ['Mark', 33]], [['Peter', 5]]]
```